# InteractionRequest CustomPopupWindow does not resize

Tags: wpf, prism

Using a prism Interactionrequest together with a CustomPopUpWindow I have the Problem, that the custom popup window does not resize.

Calling the interaction the first time, it sizes its self to the content correctly, but if I call it again, it kind of memorizes this size and does not change size according to its changed content.

Is this a known issue, or am I doing things wrong?

Regards
Rainer

```
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <InteractionRequest:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding ImportConfirmation, Mode=OneWay}">
        <InteractionRequest:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True">
            <InteractionRequest:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                <Views:ImportMachineDefintionConfirmationView/>
            </InteractionRequest:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
        </InteractionRequest:PopupWindowAction>
    </InteractionRequest:InteractionRequestTrigger>
    <InteractionRequest:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding DeleteMachineDefinitionConfirmation, Mode=OneWay}">
        <InteractionRequest:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True" >
            <InteractionRequest:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                <Views:DeleteMachineDefinitionConfirmationView/>
            </InteractionRequest:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
        </InteractionRequest:PopupWindowAction>
    </InteractionRequest:InteractionRequestTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>

private void DeleteMachineDefinitionCommandExecute(IVersionAwareMachineDefinition machineDefinition)
    {
        var deleteConfirmation =
            this.unityContainer.Resolve<IDeleteMachineDefinitionConfirmationViewModel>(
                new ParameterOverride("machineDefinitionToDelete", machineDefinition));            
        this.DeleteMachineDefinitionConfirmation.Raise(
            deleteConfirmation,
            _ =>
                {
                    if (!_.Confirmed)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    this.repository.DeleteMachineDefinition((MachineType)machineDefinition.MachineTypeId, machineDefinition.MachineNumber);
                    this.MachineDefinitions =
                        new ObservableCollection<IVersionAwareMachineDefinition>(this.repository.GetKnownVersionAwareMachineDefinitions());
                    this.SelectedMachineDefinition = null;
                });
    }
```

Comment: You actually don't show us how are you doing it now, so we cannot say whether this is right or wrong.

Comment: Added the related code (XAML+C#).